PyInstaller Executable fails to run download operation with external script despite working in pure python
I'm trying to compile a python script into an executable, but I can't properly include the external file tg-upload.py that takes care of the download operations
The relevant code in my telethongram.py is this
def download_thread():
    while True:
        link = download_queue.get()
        if link is None:
            break  # Termina il thread
        download_link_script(link)
        download_queue.task_done()

download_thread = Thread(target=download_thread)
download_thread.start()

def download_link_script(link):
    print(f'Chiamato download_link_script con il link: {link}')
    
    # Ottieni il percorso del file tg-upload.py
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        # Se l'applicazione è congelata, ottieni il percorso del file dal bundle
        tg_upload_path = os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, 'tg-upload.py')
    else:
        # Se l'applicazione non è congelata, usa il percorso relativo
        tg_upload_path = 'tg-upload.py'
    
    print(f'Percorso tg-upload.py: {tg_upload_path}')
    
    command = [sys.executable, tg_upload_path, '--profile', 'enteSoffitta', '--dl', '--links'] + link.split()
    print(f'Comando eseguito: {" ".join(command)}')
    
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    progress_updates = []  # Create an array to hold the progress updates
    while True:
        output = process.stdout.readline()
        if output == b'' and process.poll() is not None:
            break
        if output:
            try:
                output = output.decode('utf-8')  # Decode the bytes to a string
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                output = output.decode('latin-1')  # Fallback to latin-1 decoding
            print(output.strip())
            match = re.search(r'(\d+(\.\d+)?%)', output.strip())  # Extract the progress percentage
            if match:
                progress_updates.append(match.group(1))  # Add progress update to array
    
    # Cattura e stampa l'output di errore
    stderr_output = process.stderr.read()
    if stderr_output:
        try:
            stderr_output = stderr_output.decode('utf-8')
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            stderr_output = stderr_output.decode('latin-1')
        print(f'Errore: {stderr_output}')
    
    rc = process.poll()
    return jsonify(progress_updates)  # Send progress updates as JSON

@app.route('/scarica', methods=['GET'])
def scarica():
    print('Ricevuta richiesta GET a /scarica')
    link = request.args.get('message_link')
    if link:
        response = download_link_script(link)  # Get the Response object
        return response  # Return the Response object directly
    else:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Nessun message_link fornito'}), 400
        
@app.route('/scarica_multi', methods=['POST'])
def scarica_multi():
    print('Ricevuta richiesta POST a /scarica_multi')
    links = request.json.get('message_link')
    if links:
        for link in links:
            download_queue.put(link)  # Aggiungi ogni link alla coda
        return jsonify({'message': 'Download iniziati'})
    else:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Nessun message_link fornito'}), 400

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all() 
    app.run(debug=False)
    download_queue.put(None)
    download_thread.join()

To compile in windows I'm trying to include the file in this way
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "tg-upload.py:." --add-data "static:static" --add-data "templates:templates" telethongram.py

but the problem is that even if it is included, then the download operations do not start with the telethongram.exe executable, while with the pure python script I have no problems downloading with tg-upload.py
There is a problem importing tg-upload.py into the telethongram.exe executable
Also under linux problem is the same
